# How to force a picture's location and still use overpic

Tags: graphics, positioning, memoir

I want to insert a picture, and use `overpic` to label it, in between two paragraphs of text, like so:

```
Here is my first paragraph of text.
\begin{figure}[htb] \centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figure/mypicture.pdf}
\put(20, 20){$A$}
\end{overpic}
\caption{This is mypicture.pdf, with the label $A$.}
\end{figure}
Here is my second paragraph of text.
In order to understand this paragraph, you first need to see the picture.
```

But depending on the content of those paragraphs, and on other pictures that are inserted before or after them, mypicture.pdf doesn't always end up in the right place.  Is there a way to force it to be there (as in `\includegraphic`), while still being able to use `overpic`?

Comment: Just use `center` instead of `figure` (and don't say `\centering`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use simply a `center` environment instead of the floating `figure` environment; if a caption is required, you can use `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

Here is my first paragraph of text.
\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figure/mypicture.pdf}
\put(20, 20){$A$}
\end{overpic}
\captionof{figure}{This is mypicture.pdf, with the label $A$.}
\end{center}
Here is my second paragraph of text.
In order to understand this paragraph, you first need to see the picture.

\end{document}
```

If the `memoir` document class is used, then there's no need to use additional packages to produce the caption outside a floating environment, since the class has a built-in mechanism (the `\newfixedcaption` command) to this effect:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}

% we declare a new type of caption for captioning images outside
% the figure environment,
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}

\begin{document}

Here is my first paragraph of text.
\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figure/mypicture.pdf}
\put(20, 20){$A$}
\end{overpic}
\figcaption{This is mypicture.pdf, with the label $A$.}
\end{center}
Here is my second paragraph of text.
In order to understand this paragraph, you first need to see the picture.

\end{document}
```