# Non-italicized text in a \newfixedcaption

Tags: formatting, captions, memoir, theorems

This is a very specific follow-up question to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38642/9757) given to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38641/9757).

I want to insert a picture, and use `overpic` to label it, in between two paragraphs of text in a `thm` environment (using the `memoir` class).  I use the `center` environment for the picture, and a `\newfixedcaption` to label it.  However, within the caption, the text is still italicized--as if it were part of the `thm` environment--when it really shouldn't be.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\noindent Here is my first paragraph of text.

\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{./mypicture.pdf}
\put(20, 20){$A$}
\end{overpic}
\figcaption{This is mypicture.pdf, with the label $A$.
For some reason, this caption is italicized.}
\end{center}

\noindent Here is my second paragraph of text.
In order to understand this paragraph, you first need to see the picture.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memoir` provides the `\captionnamefont` and `\captiontitlefont` macros which format the respective parts of captions. By default, these  macros are defined as empty, i.e., a caption's font will resemble that of the surrounding text -- which in your case (caption inside theorem) is italic. Solution: Add, e.g., the following to your preamble:

```
\captionnamefont{\normalfont}
\captiontitlefont{\normalfont}
```

See section 10.6 of the `memoir` manual for details.